# MySQL error on creating an update trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

im creating a mysql trigger (totally new to triggers) and im getting an error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

the code is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER contact_name
AFTER UPDATE ON contacts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET full_name = CONCAT(NEW.fname,' ',NEW.lname) 
        WHERE contacts_id = $contacts_id;
END;
```

I am totally lost to why its not letting me setup the trigger.

Comment: Can you please describe what the purpose of your trigger is ?

Comment: on every update of the 'contacts' table i want 'full_name' column to equal CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) 'fname' and 'lname' are also columns of the contacts table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SET full_name = CONCAT(NEW.fname,' ',NEW.lname) WHERE contacts_id = $contacts_id;

This is not valid syntax :

- `SET` does not take a `WHERE` clause (sql queries do, like `SELECT` , `UPDATE`, `INSERT`)
- `$contacts_id` is completely unknown to the RDBMS

You seem to be trying to automatically update the value of field `full_name` value when an `UPDATE` is executed againts table `contacts`.

In order to do this you would need to use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger (instead of `AFTER UPDATE`) where you could set the value `NEW.full_name`. Usually it is also a good practice to make sure that the value was not given in the update query before setting it :

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo BEFORE UPDATE ON contacts 
FOR EACH ROW
    IF NEW.full_name IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.full_name := CONCAT(
            COALESCE(NEW.fname, OLD.fname),
            ' ',
            COALESCE(NEW.lname, OLD.fname)
        );
    END IF;;
```

Comment: thanks. My only concern is that it uses before. will it update the latest update as well? or is there an option to use "after"?

Comment: and i still getting the same exact error, just different line **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7 **

Comment: also shouldnt the contact bracket be closed too?

Comment: @AndrewKorneychuk : yes there was a typo in my query where a closing bracket was missing for `CONCAT` : I just fixed it.

Comment: @AndrewKorneychuk : yes the trigger fires for every update, just before the row is updated, which gives you a chance to modify the values before they are written to database.